# How does one capture a measure (number and/or unit) and a measured matter and always assures the same measure format/pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, capturing-group

I am just trying to understand javascript as I am a bit new to it and its such a power-full language.

I wanted to know how to re-arrange words and numbers in a string so some words can always be in the front. So in this case the number and measurement will always be in front of the value.

For example the desired output from input:

```
Function input: Wood Plank 1 cm
Function output: 1 cm Wood Plank

Function input: Lawn Mower 1
Function output: 1 Lawn Mower

Function input: Tape Measure
Function output: Tape Measure
```

I have this regex that I made which works but I need to know how to apply it

```
const unitCapturingRegX = (/^(?<amount>¼|½|¾|\d+\/\d+|\d+)\s*(?<value>.*)$/);
```

I have got some measurements below:

```
const measures = [
  "cm", "m", "kg", "kgs", "kilogram", "kilograms", "l", "liter" ,"tbs","meter", "inch",
];
```

This is my input Values:

```
const inputVal = [
  'Tape 1/2 cm',
  '1kg cement',
  '3 l water',
  'carbon fibre ½ inch'
]
```

Is this a possible thing to do , please can someone help me!!!

Comment: Add your measurement values to your reg exp

Comment: Hi @epascarello please can you show me the best way to do this so I can learn as well as others can learn from this answer. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the units to the end of the regualr expression

```js
var re = /(.*)\s(¼|½|¾|\d+\/\d+|\d+)\s?(cm|m|kg|kgs|kilogram|kilograms|l|liter|tbs|meter|inch)?$/;

const inputVal = [
  'Tape 1/2 cm',
  'cement 1kg',
  '1kg cement',
  '3 l water',
  'water 3 l',
  'carbon fibre ½ inch',
  'Lawn Mower 1'
]

const altered = inputVal.map(function(str) {
  return str.replace(re, "$2 $3 $1") // or "$2$3 $1"
})

console.log(altered);
```

And generating it from the array

```js
const measures = [
  "cm", "m", "kg", "kgs", "kilogram", "kilograms", "l", "liter" ,"tbs","meter", "inch",
];

var units = measures.join("|");
var re = new RegExp("(.*)\\s(¼|½|¾|\\d+\\/\\d+|\\d+)\\s?(" + units + ")?$");

const inputVal = [
  'Tape 1/2 cm',
  'cement 1kg',
  '1kg cement',
  '3 l water',
  'water 3 l',
  'carbon fibre ½ inch'
]

const altered = inputVal.map(function(str) {
  return str.replace(re, "$2 $3 $1") // or "$2$3 $1"
})

console.log(altered);
```

Comment: oh my goodness thank you so much how would I include the array values in the regex instead of adding them like this `cm|m|kg|kgs|` because with more measurements that could be difficult to type . Is there a way to include the actual `measures` array in the RegEx thank you so much by the way

Comment: You can generate the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: I have basic knowledge on Reg Ex so how would I do that you are way more talented I am new to Javascript

Comment: Oh my goodness I am sorry for bothering you again your answer really helped but it isnt working when there is just a number and no amount like an input of `Lawn Mower 1` to output `1 Lawn Mower`

Comment: How would I do that ?

Comment: You're the best. God bless you !!!!!! Thank you so much for you help!!!!! Honestly I really appreciate it !!!

Answer (score 0):

The provided approach is based on this regex [`(/^(?<left>[^¼½¾\d]+)*(?<count>¼|½|¾|\d+\/\d+|\d+)\s*(?<unit>kilograms|l|cm|m)*(?<right>.*)/)`](https://regex101.com/r/2RS9PJ/1/). There it is described in detail.

The regex takes optional *matter/material* `<left>` and/or `<right>` from a *measure* into account. A *measure* again is composed of a valid number- or fraction-`<count>` and an optional `<unit>`.

Any string value can be passed to a sanitizer function which uses its main [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Syntax) method for rearranging the [capture groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) by a [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). The second `replace` step applies also to string values that did not match the regex.

Thus, with all these steps, one assures pretty clean results regardless of the quality of the input data ...

```js
const regXMeasureAndMatter = (/^(?<left>[^¼½¾\d]+)*(?<count>¼|½|¾|\d+\/\d+|\d+)\s*(?<unit>kilograms|kilogram|kgs|kg|liter|l|tbs|inch|meter|cm|m)*(?<right>.*)/);

function rearrangeMeasureAndMatter(match, left, count, unit, right) {
  left = (left || '' ).trim();
  right = (right || '' ).trim();
  return [
  
    count,
    (unit || ''),
    [left, right].join((left && right && ', ') || '')

  ].join(' ')
}
function sanitizeMeasureAndMatter(str) {
  return str
    .replace(regXMeasureAndMatter, rearrangeMeasureAndMatter)
    .replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()
}
console.log([

  '  left   22/33   kilogram   right  ',
  '     Tape Measure     ',
  '21m  Wood Plank',
  '  3l Wood   Plank  ',
  ' Wood  Plank  20/10  cm ',
  'Lawn Mower 2/2',
  'Tape   123   Measure',
  '  Wood Plank   ½    cm  ',
  'Lawn   Mower ¾  cm',
  '  Tape     Measure  ',
  '  safas 1/2  '

].map(sanitizeMeasureAndMatter));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

A solution that generates the regex on the fly based by a unit array follows the above approach and just changes the way of how a regex is created ...

```js
const unitList = ['kilograms', 'kilogram', 'kgs', 'kg', 'liter', 'l', 'tbs', 'inch', 'meter', 'cm', 'm'];

const regXMeasureAndMatter = RegExp('^(?<left>[^¼½¾\\d]+)*(?<count>¼|½|¾|\\d+\\/\\d+|\\d+)\\s*(?<unit>' + unitList.join('|') + ')*(?<right>.*)');

function rearrangeMeasureAndMatter(match, left, count, unit, right) {
  left = (left || '' ).trim();
  right = (right || '' ).trim();
  return [
  
    count,
    (unit || ''),
    [left, right].join((left && right && ', ') || '')

  ].join(' ')
}
function sanitizeMeasureAndMatter(str) {
  return str
    .replace(regXMeasureAndMatter, rearrangeMeasureAndMatter)
    .replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()
}
console.log([

  '  left   22/33   kilogram   right  ',
  '     Tape Measure     ',
  '21m  Wood Plank',
  '  3l Wood   Plank  ',
  ' Wood  Plank  20/10  cm ',
  'Lawn Mower 2/2',
  'Tape   123   Measure',
  '  Wood Plank   ½    cm  ',
  'Lawn   Mower ¾  cm',
  '  Tape     Measure  ',
  '  safas 1/2  '

].map(sanitizeMeasureAndMatter));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```